# Asterisk answer a call not working using agi

Tags: asterisk

Anyone would like to help me for below scenario ?

```
$AGI->exec('Wait','10');
$AGI->answer();
$AGI->exec('Wait','10');
$AGI->verbose ("Audio file going to")
$AGI->exec('Playback',"test.gsm");
```

I can hear my audio file but i cant get dialstatus in cdr. I am using asterisk 13.8.2 if that can helps

Answer (score 0):

DIALSTATUS variable will be set only AFTER Dial command issues and will not be present in CDR at all.

In CDR there are no dialstatus. DISPOSITION in cdr will be set acordinly anyway.